# How to create pop up form at start of program in delphi?

Tags: delphi

Hi all,

I want to display that option form above the Main Form when application will run. So How can I display Option form with Main form in background at start?

Thanks for help.

Comment: its like pop up form with Main Form should display in background.

Comment: I tried create the option form on OnCreate or Onshow events of Main form but it displays only option form. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `OnActivate`. Have to wrap it in some code to prevent it from firing when other application forms close and the main one gets activated again however.

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
Const
{$J+}
  SettingsShown : Boolean = false;
{$J-}
begin
  if SettingsShown = false then
  begin
    Form2.ShowModal;
    SettingsShown := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I think a non-modal form would be better for any automatically-popped-up-forms, and if you are going to use modal forms, be sure that you will enventually suffer from the dreaded Z-Order bug unless you have a version of Delphi that has the fix (and you use the fix, set the window's PopupParent), or you write some special code to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `OptionForm.ShowModal` in `OnCreate` or `OnShow` create a custom message like `Const AM_ShowOptionForm = WM_APP +1` and Post a message back to your main form.

Add a message handler on your main form such as

```
Procedure RecieveOptionFormMessage(var Msg:TMessage); Message AM_ShowOptionForm
begin
    OptionForm.ShowModal;
end;
```